# I want to import commands from discord.ext but this directory error keeps coming

Tags: python, discord

code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
```

Error:

```
ValueError: mutable default <class 'discord.utils._MissingSentinel'> for field name is not allowed: use default_factory
```

This error has randomly popped up till yesterday there was no such erorr

I am trying to import commands from discord.ext to run commands

Comment: What version of python and discord.py are you using? Looks like there's already a similar question where the issue was with the version. Maybe you can use a specific older version that works at the moment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74419508/valueerror-mutable-default-class-discord-utils-missingsentinel-for-field-n

Comment: discord.py-2.1.1 on Python3.9.7 works fine on MacOS Ventura 13.2

Comment: python version is 3.11.1

Comment: `pip show discord.py` should give you the version of the package. Or `pip show py-cord`, if you're using that.

Comment: pycord is 2.0.0b5 
discord  py is 2.2.0

Comment: That seems very outdated (March 2022). If there isn't a reason for you to stick to that specific version, you can probably fix your issues by updating it. `pip install --upgrade py-cord`
Latest version is currently [py-cord==2.4.0](https://pypi.org/project/py-cord/)

Comment: Please consider updating your question to include these details (version of python and the packages you use). There's also the `discord.py` package, which is initialized the same way as `py-cord`, so from your question there was no way to know which package you were using.

Comment: I just re-read your message, discord.py's latest version is 2.1.1 - also you should only install one of them and remove the other.

Comment: thanks !! I updated and it works now !