# How can I use Discord.py to add a role to a specific user once they've levelled up?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to add a role to a user on my discord server for when someone levels up, but I keep getting the error

> " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'"

.  Here is the relevant code:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

async def assignRoles(message, level):
  server = bot.get_guild(<ID GOES HERE>)
  role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name = "LEVEL 5-10")
  try:
    await message.author.id.add_roles(role)
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
  else:
    print("hooray")
```

I have tried many different methods that I've found online but no success.  Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [`bot.get_guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.get_guild) is returning None. Are you actually passing an ID in to that?

```py
server = bot.get_guild(YOUR_SERVER_ID)
```

If that *still* returns `None`, it means that it isn't in the cache so you will have to [fetch it](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_guild).

```py
server = await bot.fetch_guild(YOUR_SERVER_ID)
```

To prevent making unnecessary API calls you could combine it to do:

```py
server = bot.get_guild(YOUR_SERVER_ID)
if not server:
    server = await bot.fetch_guild(YOUR_SERVER_ID)
```

Comment: I did that and now I am getting the error: "AttributeError: '_MissingSentinel' object has no attribute 'is_set'"

Comment: That's a different issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74419508/valueerror-mutable-default-class-discord-utils-missingsentinel-for-field-n Make sure to update your discord.py to the latest version. `pip install -U discord.py`